# Angular 5 - How to test App component created successfully with relying on asynchronous service?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular5, angular-test

How to test AppComponent created successfully when it has dependency on a service with promise constructor? Where to put the done statement in the app.spec.ts?

App.spec.ts

```
describe("AppComponent", () => {
    var fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent> = null;
    var cmp: AppComponent = null;

    beforeEach(done => {
        OidcService.oidcStartup(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [AppModule],
                providers: [
                    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: "/" },
                    Broadcaster
                ]
            }).compileComponents();
            done();
        });
    });

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        this.fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        this.cmp = this.fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    }));

    it(
        "should create the app",
        done => {
            expect(this.cmp).toBeTruthy();

        },
        60000
    );
});
```

App.module.ts

```
...        
        providers: [StorageService],
        entryComponents: [
        ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Storage.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
    public tenantID: string = null;
    constructor(private base64Svc: Base64Service) {
        // NOOP
        var self = this;
        OidcService.userMgr.getUser().then(user => {
            self.tenantID = user.profile.tenant_id;
        });
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to mock this service. 
You can mock it with TestBed Api like so:

mock object/class, for example:

```
let storageMock = {}
```

and then use it in TestBed:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule],
    providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: "/" },
        Broadcaster,
        { provide: StorageService, useValue: storageMock}
    ]
}).compileComponents();
```